# JSon.net linq join

Tags: c#, json, facebook, linq, json.net

I grab json from facebook like so:

> > me?fields=albums.fields(id,name,photos.fields(source)), feed.fields(id, message, picture, link, source, object_id, name, description, type).limit(20)

Here is my Json (edited down, but structure intact)

```
{
  "albums": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "812",
        "name": "Timeline Photos",
        "created_time": "2010-07-16T17:14:34-05:00",
        "photos": {
          "data": [
            {
              "source": "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/482_800000000000992_775_n.jpg",
              "id": "800000000000992",
              "created_time": "2014-04-24T13:05:39-05:00"
            }           
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
   },
  "feed": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "827_805407852819991",
        "message": "Picture Description!!",
        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-0/482_800000000000992_775_s.jpg",
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=800000000000992&set=a.138763042817812.20386.117612894932827&type=1&relevant_count=1",
        "object_id": "800000000000992",
        "type": "photo",
        "created_time": "2014-04-24T13:05:39-05:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": "827"
}
```

The reason I grab the albums table is because for some reason "feed" is not containing a "source". Is there a way to use linq to put the source in the feed field for the picture? You can see in albums.data.photos.id = feed.data.object_id
I think an inner join in linq might would work, but am unsure how to do it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will join the data in the way you want, at least for your example:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(s);
var q = from albumData in root.albums.data
        from photoData in albumData.photos.data
        join feedData in root.feed.data on photoData.id equals feedData.object_id
        select new { feedData.message, photoData.source }; // or whatever
```

Using the following classes, generated by http://json2csharp.com/:

```
public class Datum2
{
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
}

public class Photos
{
    public List<Datum2> data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public Photos photos { get; set; }
}

public class Albums
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum3
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string object_id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
}

public class Feed
{
    public List<Datum3> data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Albums albums { get; set; }
    public Feed feed { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

See the [LINQ documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx) for more on `from`, `join`, etc.

Comment: Cheers! Works perfect.